# how to simplify this php code using array

Tags: php, loops

I have a 'loop' to go through but I can't work out how to do this. I want to do something like

array1=(2,3,10,11,13)
array2=(20,22,24,27,29)

and then loop though for each.

Here is the long hand version that I want to produce.

Thanks in advance...

```
<?php if($values['2']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['2']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['20']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['20']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q1. '.$values['20']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['3']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['3']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['23']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['23']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q2. '.$values['23']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['10']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['10']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['22']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['22']['value'] != ''){echo $values['10']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['11']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['11']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['24']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['24']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q4. '.$values['24']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['12']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['12']['description'].'<br/>';} ?> 
<?php if($values['25']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['25']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q5. '.$values['25']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['13']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['13']['description'].'<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['27']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['27']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q6. '.$values['27']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['21']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['21']['description'].'<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['26']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['26']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q7. '.$values['26']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['29']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['29']['description'].'<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['49']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['49']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q8. '.$values['49']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['39']['value'] == 'No'){echo $values['39']['description'].'<br/>';} ?>
<?php if($values['48']['label'] == 'Other' && $values['48']['value'] != ''){echo 'Q9. '.$values['48']['value']; echo '<br/>';} ?>
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain it better? I can't figure out what it is that you are trying to do...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean... You want to loop through both arrays at the same time? I mean loop array1[1] array2[1] loop array1[2] array2[2] etcetera? Or is is it array1[1] array1[2]... then array2[1] array[2]... ?

Answer (score 1):

my bad, I was doing it wrong!!

```
 <?php
 $risk_numbers = array(
                    '2' => '20',
                    '3' => '23',
                    '10' => '22',
                    '11' => '24',
                    '12' => '25',
                    '13' => '27',
                    '21' => '26',
 );

foreach($risk_numbers as $description => $other) {
  if($values[$description]['value'] == 'No'){echo $values[$description]['description'].'<br/>';}  
  if($values[$other]['label'] == 'Other' && $values[$other]['value'] != ''){echo $values[$other]['value']; echo '<br/>';}
}
?>
```